# I want to convert an IEnumerable to List or IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, ienumerable

I have an `IEnumerable` return list from service that I need to map to my IEnumerable of my object type. Its a direct mapping:

But I am getting the following error:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2
```

I tried using Singe/First but that didn't let the application run itself, so doesn't help me.

```
private IEnumerable<Doctor> From(IEnumerable<DoctorsList> doctorList)
{
    var doctors = new List<Doctor>
    {
        new Doctor()
        {
            Name = doctorList.Select(e => e.Name).ToString() ?? null,
            Id = doctorList.Select(e => e.Id).ToString() ?? null
        }
    };

    return doctors;
}
```

Comment: What is that object `DoctorList`? shouldn't it be `List<Doctor>`?

Comment: `System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2` is not an error message, that's a type name. Can you please tell us what the error message is?

Comment: @fubo: Yes thats the doctor not list

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: I dont see error but i dont get values I want

Comment: So you have 2 classes for doctor - `Doctor`  and `DoctorList`

Comment: That means you're "outputting" the object incorrectly, since you haven't posted *that* code, there's nothing we can do to help you with that. You've probably tried something like `Console.WriteLine(doctors);` which, unless the object in `doctors` have overridden `ToString()`, will simply output the name of the type. You need to format your objects into a string, or implement `ToString()` (if you can) to get what you want in this case, but again, you have not posted this code so I cannot do more than guess at the real cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can achieve this by using a simple `Select`, Take a look into the code below:

```
private IEnumerable<Doctor> From(IEnumerable<DoctorsList> doctorList)
{
   return  doctorList.Select(x=> new Doctor()
                                {
                                   Name = x.Name?? null,
                                   Id = x.Id?? null
                               });
}
```

Comment: You are close to correct, because, earlier I had individual properties and used similar select one the way you did. Now my superior asked me to use a object and list of that object which is why I am struggling. I am trying out your solution now, will keep you posted in few mins on how it goes

Comment: Unfortunately your solution gives me run time error

Comment: I can help you if you tell me what was the error saying, have you tried by removing the `.Tostring()`

Comment: Yes, I did exactly what you gave here, but there is no error, it breaks in runtime

Comment: Ok, I get the same error that I pasted above, however, I do get the resultview having the Name and ID. Why still that system.linq error showing?

Comment: Thank you un-lucky, your solution helped me and served what I want